# Embeded Youtube video doesn't show at front end

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4, jce

I have a problem with my website. In the joomla template I have BluePage Builder. At homepage I've put an HTML tab with iframe code for a youtube video. I have changed the parameters at Global Configuration to No Filtering. I checked Allow IFrame to JCE Editor. My website is [kaltsas.gr](http://kaltsas.gr). It doesn't delete the html code at editor but also it doesn't show it at front end.

Answer (score 1):

Well, besides the point that you should ASAP update your Joomla to 3.6.4 *(check the official Anouncement [Joomla! 3.6.4 Released](https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5678-joomla-3-6-4-released.html) and also search JSE for `3.6.4`)*,
from the link you provided it seems that Default Menu Item (Homepage) for Greek language DOES NOT have the same module like other two languages (EN and BG) have.

They both have following DIV
`<div style="max-width:700px;height:450px;" class="st-youtube ">
  <iframe width="700" height="450" 
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/R1h6ywml0lE?wmode=transparent&amp;autoplay=1&amp;
    loop=1&amp;controls=1" class="videoembed">
  </iframe>
</div>`

and video is shown correctly, while Greek homepage has only `<p>` paragraph with `<img>` image tag in it with embed code changed to `data-mce-json`, which might be the problem with JCE, I'm not sure, so try updating it too.

It is not possible to say for certain just by looking at frontend and without access to admin, but you should check what is set for other two languages as homepage menu item which is working, and duplicate it for Greek homepage too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Mikan . First, I can't update to 3.6.4. It gives me 500 server error. Second, I don't want to do it like the other two languages cause it shows relative videos after the video finishes. But when I put HTML module at Greek Homepage it didn't show other videos. But it worked for a while. Now it doesn't show the video at all.

Comment: I had to change JCE Editor. It worked at TinyMCE.